# How to set margin for cell in tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I tried to set a margin for a **certain cell** in my TableView by using code as below:

```
cell.layoutMargin.left = 20
```

However, when I launched the application, it changes nothing on the appearance. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the content you added has the constraint related to the margin

Comment: Is your tableView static or dynamic?

Comment: it's dynamic @Xcoder

Comment: Update in Swift 4 : cell.layoutMargins.left = 20

Answer (score -1):

For margins to take effect in any UIView, any constraints must have the "Constrain to margins" checked. Otherwise, the margins will not change any subview's constraints on the superview.

[image]

If you are adding constraints with Swift, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) is an example of adding constraints relative to margins from Apple. The key part is:

```
// Get the superview's layout
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide

// Pin the leading edge of myView to the margin's leading edge
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Ensure that your view is being updated and that any changes you are making to UIView is from the main thread.

To give a more thorough answer, more data is needed on your current auto layout setup.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution or alternative for this problem after getting help from my colleague, what we did was creating an IBOutlet for the constraint (which I just discover).  So in UITableviewCell class, i add this line of code :

```
@IBOutlet var boxLeadingContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And in UITableView I set the margin for the specified cell like this:

```
cell.boxLeadingContraint.constant = 10
```

Note: I did this on a UIImageView inside the cell not on the cell itself. Any feedback or advice will be appreciated.